# Apply physics to player using bullet physics

Tags: c++, opengl-3, bulletphysics

So I've had a lot of problems trying to properly get physics applied to the play by using bullet physics. I've tried kinematic bodies to an unsuccess. I am now trying now trying to use a rigid body I've had little successfully. Pasted below is the updating code for the player's matrix and the rigid bodies location. My question is how could I update the player's position correctly.

Update Player's rigid body and the camera's matrix *the gCamera.matrix is just the projection and view matrix's multiplyed together

```
 physics.PlayerBody->getMotionState()->getWorldTransform(k);
k.getOpenGLMatrix(glm::value_ptr(gCamera.matrix));

btVector3 j;
j = physics.PlayerBody->getLinearVelocity();

gCamera.position.x = j.getX();
gCamera.position.y = j.getY();
gCamera.position.z = j.getZ();


btVector3 pastPos;
pastPos.setX(gCamera.position.x);
pastPos.setY(gCamera.position.y);
pastPos.setZ(gCamera.position.z);

gCamera.GetInput(window);


float lVelocityX = sin(gCamera.horizontalAngle * 3.14159265359 / 180) * 2;
float lVelocityY = physics.PlayerBody->getLinearVelocity().y();
float lVelocityZ = cos(gCamera.verticalAngle * 3.14159265359 / 180) * 2;
//physics.PlayerBody->setLinearVelocity(btVector3(lVelocityX, lVelocityY, lVelocityZ));
physics.PlayerBody->setLinearVelocity(btVector3(gCamera.position.x, gCamera.position.y, gCamera.position.z));

btTransform t;
t.setFromOpenGLMatrix(glm::value_ptr(gCamera.matrix));
physics.PlayerBody->getMotionState()->setWorldTransform(t);
physics.PlayerBody->setCenterOfMassTransform(t);
```

Comment: It's very hard to answer a question containing a bunch of code along with a description that suggests "something is wrong".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be in control of where the player is, then use kinematic. I know you've had trouble but that's just the best solution.

If you want physics to move player, you need a rigid body and apply forces to move it.

It is not possible to move a rigid body yourself in a reliable way. Where I have had to teleport objects in the past I have removed and added a new rigid body, but you do not want to be doing that every frame for your player.